# Why do some microwave meal instructions violate the 'Specific Absorption Rate' rule?

Tags: thermodynamics, microwaves, applied-physics

*[Do Microwave oven heating times grow linearly with Wattage? Calculating optimal heating time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67077/do-microwave-oven-heating-times-grow-linearly-with-wattage-calculating-optimal)* states that the product of the microwave power and cooking time should be constant. However, some meals have instructions such as "11 mins at 700 W, or 10 min at 900 W". What other factors cause such deviation from the rule?

Comment: Thermal diffusion into the center.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that causes 29% more power reducing cooking time by only 9%. Can you please explain?

Comment: Because if the outside is molten lava and the inside is still cold the eating experience will not be good.

Answer (score 0):

> What other factors cause such deviation from the rule?

Making sure the food is evenly heated. In general, most of the microwave energy is absorbed in depths of about 2.5-3.8 cm. See [https://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/multimedia/multimedia_pub/multimedia_pub_fsf_43_02.html#:~:text=Although%20heat%20is%20produced%20directly,or%201%20to%201.5%20inches](https://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/multimedia/multimedia_pub/multimedia_pub_fsf_43_02.html#:%7E:text=Although%20heat%20is%20produced%20directly,or%201%20to%201.5%20inches)).

If the rule were simply "the product of the microwave power and cooking time should be constant" than in the example the 1100 w oven could run continuously for 3.5 minutes and the 700 w oven run continuously for 5.5 minutes.  But that's not what the instructions said.  Power is interrupted after 2 minutes for the 1000 w oven and after 3 minutes for the 700 w oven, apparently to allow for heat to penetrate by conduction and stirring ensuring more even temperatures.

> However, some meals have instructions such as "11 mins at 700 W, or 10
> min at 900 W".

In your example it appears that, for the given "meal", for some reason it is not critical for the rule to be followed exactly. I suppose it depends on the "meal".

Hope this helps.